# using bash without arrow keys

Tags: bash

I am using bash on a virtual machine. For some reason arrow keys don't work there. Is it possible to use some other key kombination (like HJKL in vi) to move left/right/up/down?

(it's OpenBSD if it helps)

edit: I will also add I know the reason why they don't work and it's pretty much unfixable (and it's not the problem I want to solve right now)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
set -o vi
```

Then use Esc and 'hjkl' to navigate.

You can also do this:

```
set -o emacs
```

And use ctrl-p, ctrl-n, etc. for navigation.

I have VI mode set in my .bashrc so it's immediately available.

EDIT: [here's](http://www.catonmat.net/download/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet.pdf) a cheat sheet for VI mode in Bash.  It's a PDF, so consider yourself warned ;)

[Here's](http://www.catonmat.net/download/readline-emacs-editing-mode-cheat-sheet.pdf) a cheat sheet for Emacs mode in Bash -- just to cover my bases.  It's also a PDF.

Comment: Glad to help :) I'm posting a link w/a cheat sheet for VI: warning, PDF.

Answer (score 5):

In Emacs mode, it's Ctrl-B and F (backward and forward one character), and Ctrl-P and N (previous and next line)

Answer (score 0):

The arrow keys on the numpad also work (4,8,6,2) and send a different keycode.